# Doing operations in a while loop until a key combination is invoked c++

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, g++

I have the following issue. I want to do some certain operations in a Linux terminal until the key combination CTRL+D is invoked. I have found a C++ library function for Windows that can do this, but no easy solution for Linux. The code skeleton will be something like this:

```
while(!invoked){ //Until CTRL+D is pressed
//Do something
}
//Continue when CTRL+D is invoked
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure CTRL+D generates a signal.. ?

Comment: Fail, it's EOF. My bad.

Comment: Are you talking about "read some input until CTRL-D is pressed", or "Draw figures and play music" type of "do something". The distinction is quite important as to whether Giueseppe Pes solution is right, or we should go down some other route.

Comment: Input stuff until CTRL-D is pressed, it isn't more complicated than that =)

Comment: @Nbr44 Whether it generates a signal or not depends on the last `stty`.  Under Linux, he could always call `tcsetattr` to make control D generate a signal.  (A better solution is to use curses on both platforms, and not have to worry about the system dependencies yourself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This interrupts the cycle when the combination `CRTL + D'  is inserted :

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Note in Linux is `CRTL-D` stands for EOF. It is the equivalent of `CTRL-Z` in windows.

Comment: And what happens if the user doesn't input anything?

Comment: The application is blocked in the `getchar()` function, waiting for an input.  I see what you mean :D ! The problem is that the `getchar` function calls a BLOCKING `read` system call. This may be solved by making the `read` not blocking and handling correctly the error `EAGAIN` and `EWOULDBLOCK`.
To be honest, I have never tried over the `STDIN` but it should work!

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to *wait for `Ctrl+D`* is to read smth from `std::cin` and then check for `EOF` in a stream.
the problem is: this call would block. so *doing smth* should occur in **some other** thread. then, you have to signal (via conditional variable for example) to that *worker thread* from the waiter...

Answer (score 0):

Use [getch](http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/man/html.CURSES/getch.CURSES.html) from (n)curses library. As zaufi already explained, checking for `EOF` while reading from standard input, with, e.g. `getchar`, is like checking for `Ctrl-D`, but it's a blocking operation. `getch` is non-blocking (in `nodelay` mode), so more suitable for things like, for example, games.